# C populating array without being asked to

Tags: c, arrays

I'm playing around in C with some basics. I have an array that I am populating at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with a basic for loop. The problem is: when I try to print it out, it prints out weird values in positions that I never intended to touch (positions 6 - 13).

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSIZE 16

int main()
{
  int array[MAXSIZE];
  int array2[MAXSIZE] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
        array[i] = i;
  }

  for( i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++)
  //for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array2) / sizeof(int); i++)
  {
        printf("%d", array2[i]);
  }

 // printf("%lf\n", array[2]);

  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

0 1 2 3 4 5 822123896 32766 810140152 32643 816205824 32643 816288200 32643 0 0

0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Note: `array` is the problem. `array2` is just another tester that seems to work correctly. Is this just the way memory works in C? *Why do the last 2 values in `array` go back to being '0's then?!*

Comment: That is the way uninitialized arrays work in C, yes.

Comment: " I have an array that I am populating at positions 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with a basic for loop." --> " I have an array that I am **partially** populating (assigning) ..."

Comment: You are declaring the first array but not initializing it.

Comment: "it prints out weird values in positions that I never intended to touch (positions 6 - 13)."  Why did code then touch them by reading them?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty" variable. Once you declare it, it always has *something* in it. Either what you put there, or whatever was left over in memory from some other process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array` hasn't been initialized, and is not defined at file scope, so its values are indeterminate.  You later *assign* values to certain elements of the array, however this is not the same as initializing.

When you then print the full array, those indeterminate values get printed.  As to why some of those values are 0, as all unassigned values are indeterminate, 0 is as good a value as any other.  Note also that an indeterminate value could be a trap representation, which means that it is not a valid representation for that datatype.  If you attempt to read a trap representation, you invoke undefined behavior.

In contrast, `array2` *is* initialized.  You give values for the first 6 elements of the array, and the rest are initialized to 0.

Comment: UV for _indeterminate_: "either an unspecified value or a trap representation".

Comment: You might add that zero is just as likely to turn up in uninitialized memory as any other value.

Answer (score -1):

> Note: array1 is the problem. array2 is just another tester, that seems to work correctly. Is this just the way memory works in C? Why do the last 2 values in array1 go back to being '0's then?!

This is undefined behavior and your program is free to do anything it wants.

Comment: It is not the program "that is free to do anything it wants".  It is the compiler tool chain that is free to generate code that may or may not initialize those elements of the array.

Answer (score -1):

[C99 Section 6.7.8 Initializers](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/C99/html/6.7.8.html)

> **1671** If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than
>   there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in
>   a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.

And `static int` is **0** as default. That's why `array2` has trailing **0**'s.

Comment: OP asked why _array1_ has trailing zeros, not _array2_